# How to get text from input-textfield to dynamic-textfield on other frame as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I have an input text field and an button what `gotoAndStop()` to the next frame where an dynamic textfield is where the same text has to appear what is filled in in the insert textfield so first frame:

```
stop();
var insert.text = true;
go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(2); 
}
```

and the second frame something like this I think:

```
stop();
output.text = insert.text
```

but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputText:String;

go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

    inputText = inputTXT.text;
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

And on the second frame:

```
outputTXT.text = inputText;
```

In this code, `inputTXT` is the input textbox and `outputTXT` is the dynamic textbox on the other frame.

I hope this is what you wanted! :D

Comment: is it possible to go to frame 2 but after some proceedings to display the text on for example frame 23

Comment: beside that if I type in some text in the uotput text box some letters are not displayed what could be the reason for this??

Comment: 1. Yes it is possible.

Comment: 2. It should be because the font is not embedded. You can embed a font by pressing Embed in the textbox properties. If you don't want to embed a font, you can change the textbox to "Use device fonts" via the dropdown menu in the properties panel.

Comment: do you know how I can set an maxChars to the inputText and how I can set that every textfield is filled in before you can click on a button??

Comment: To set `maxChars` on an input textbox, simply click on the textbox, go to properties panel, and set Max Chars to whatever you want.

Comment: to check if a textbox is filled, `if (inputTXT.text.length > 0)`  check every textbox that way, and if everything results as `true`, then do whatever you want when the button is clicked

Answer (score -1):

With the help of some other forum inputs, this would be a working way:

```
var myInput:TextField;
var myOut:TextField;
go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    myOut.text = "This is my output text> " + myInput.text + "!"
    gotoAndStop(2);
    //do whatever you want
}
```